# Order a data frame according to a given order

Tags: r, dataframe

Probably an easy question.

I have a `data.frame` (names of samples, their factor level, and replicate of the factor level):

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("DP_A","DP_B","PA_A","PA_B","PA_C"),
                 level=c("DP","DP","PA","PA","PA"),
                 replicate=c("A","B","A","B","C"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

and a given desired order of one of its columns - the factor level:

```
level.order <- c("PA","DP")
```

So I'd like to order `df` by `level.order` (meaning `df$level`).

Bonus is if I can add to secondarily to `level.order` I can order by `df$replicate` which can either be a `character` (as in this example), an `integer`, or a combination of them (e.g., A1, A2, etc)

In this case the ordered `df` would be:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("PA_A","PA_B","PA_C","DP_A","DP_B"),
                 level=c("PA","PA","PA","DP","DP"),
                 replicate=c("A","B","C","A","B"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are couple of options.  One is to `match` the 'level' column with `level.order' to get the numeric index and then`order` based on it

```
df[order(match(df$level, level.order)),]
```

Or convert the 'level' to `factor` specifying the `levels` as 'level.order' and then `order` on it

```
df[order(factor(df$level, levels = level.order)),]
```